How do you change application exec strings in Unity?
I've got a few programs that need to have --no-sandbox appended to their execution in the application drawer. How do I do this?

You've not told us your release of Ubuntu Unity

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

This question is similar to: How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To change the Exec= line of an application:

Copy the .desktop launcher that needs to be changed to ~/.local/share/applications if the change is to affect your user only, or to /usr/local/share/applications if the change is to affect all users.
Open the copy, and add the desired flag to the command specified on the line that starts with Exec=

Note:

You need to have root permissions if you work in /usr/local/share/applications.
To help you find the relevant desktop file, you can use the command find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H "$1" {} \; 2>/dev/null, where you should replace the $1 with, for example, Name=Terminal if you want to find .desktop launchers that cause "Terminal" to be displayed in the application menu.
If you find multiple files, then the one appearing in the first applications subdirectory of any of the directories listed in the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable will be the one that takes effect. You can see the contents of that variable with the command printenv XDG_DATA_DIRS

